# I am installing laminate flooring over the course of several days. Do I need to use the standard 48 hour acclimitization period?

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, engineered-flooring

I am installing laminate flooring. Due to work and household schedules a relatively small installation job is likely to stretch out over 3 to 4 days. Given this slow installation pace do I need to let the flooring acclimate for the typical 48 hours or can I start installing early and let it acclimate in place?

My thinking is that any expansion or contraction which occurs will happen on the pieces which are installed first when they have no weight and lots of open edges. The remaining pieces will acclimate normally over the duration of the project sitting in their boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "48 hour" timeline assumes the flooring cartons are laid out to "acclimate", with air only getting above the cartons.

Get air underneath them. Take your first day or two's worth of packages and lean them against a wall so air can access them on both sides.   If you want even faster adjustment, bust them out of packages and fan them out individually for a few hours.